# Issue with exposing the query in GRAPHQL-JAVA

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am Newbie to Graphql-Java, I am trying to load two *.graphqls file as array  in to schema. Each schema has separate query defined. After server startup, I see only the query in last file got exposed. My code below.

A.graphqls

```
type Query{
    queryOne(param : Param) : ResponseOne
    queryTwo(param : Param) : ResponseTwo
}
```

B.graphqls

```
type Query{
    queryThree(param : Param, param1 : Param1) : ResponseThree
}
```

I see only "queryThree" got exposed.

I am loading like below.

```
        String[] graphlList = new String[]
      {"graphqls/A.graphqls","graphqls/B.graphqls"};

        GraphQLSchema gSchema = null;
        SchemaParser schemaFile = SchemaParser.newParser()
                .files(graphlList)
                .resolvers(
                    all resolvers go here
                ).dictionary(
                        all Directory  go here
                    ).scalars(
                        all userdefined scalar defined here.
                    ).build();

            gSchema = schemaFile.makeExecutableSchema();
            return gSchema;
```

Please highlight, where I am making wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the `extend` keyword in the second schema, so it overrides the definition from the first.

```
extend type Query{
    queryThree(param : Param, param1 : Param1) : ResponseThree
}
```